# quis dabit mihi ut venias in cor meum

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This is from Augustine's Confessions:

??? quis dabit mihi ??? ut venias in cor meum et inebries illud, ut obliviscar mala mea et unum bonum meum amplectar, te?

which is translated as:

Oh! that Thou wouldest enter into my heart, and inebriate it, that I may forget my ills, and embrace Thee, my sole good!

I don't get the 'quis dabit mihi' part.  As far as I know 'dabit' is future 3rd person indicative active.  Does 'do/dabit' here mean 'permit' or 'make it happen'?  Or does it mean: "give me (the ability such you would) enter?"

Also, what does 'quis' refer to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The context of this quote (according to the Loeb edition) is:

> Quis mihi dabit adquiescere in te? Quis dabit mihi ut venias in cor meum…? Quid mihi es?

Note the parallel structure: Augustine is asking *quis dabit mihi* followed by a clause acting like a noun (with either an infinitive or *ut*). So *quis* "who?" is the subject, *mihi* "(to) me" is the indirect object, and that clause is the direct object. (*Quis* is specifically "who?", the interrogative, with the question mark. "Who", the relative, without the question mark, would be *quī*.)

This particular usage of *dare* (with a whole clause as its object) is numbered IIB in Lewis and Short: "grant, consent, permit". In other words, Augustine is asking, "*who will allow me* to find peace in You? *Who will allow me* to (have/let) You enter my heart?"

Comment: I wonder if this is a calque from Hebrew, where "who will give that X?" is a conventional way of saying "I wish that X".

Comment: Seem likes the translator took too many liberties in my opinion.  Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: @TKR I had the same thought. I checked and Psalm 54:7 is quite close: “et dixi quis dabit mihi pinnas columbae ut volem et requiescam”